# MySql very slow count on query with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a view for mysql :

```
CREATE VIEW
    loggingquarantine_quarantine ( id, mail_id, partition_tag, content, rs, subject, sender, TIME,
    spam_level, size, sid, email ) AS
SELECT
    concat(CAST(`mr`.`mail_id` AS CHAR(255) charset utf8),CAST(`mr`.`partition_tag` AS CHAR(255)
    charset utf8))      AS `id`,
    `mr`.`mail_id`       AS `mail_id`,
    `mr`.`partition_tag` AS `partition_tag`,
    `mr`.`content`      AS `content`,
    `mr`.`rs`           AS `rs`,
    `m`.`subject`       AS `subject`,
    `m`.`from_addr`     AS `sender`,
    `m`.`time_num`      AS `TIME`,
    `m`.`spam_level`    AS `spam_level`,
    `m`.`size`          AS `size`,
    `m`.`sid`           AS `sid`,
    `maddr`.`email`          AS `email`
FROM
    (((`msgrcpt` `mr` JOIN `msgs` `m`
ON
    (
                `m`.`partition_tag` = `mr`.`partition_tag`
        AND
                `m`.`mail_id` = `mr`.`mail_id`
    )
)
JOIN `maddr` maddr
ON
    (
        `mr`.`rid` = `maddr`.`id`
    )
))
```

When I try to make a count for this view it take about 13min for 2.5 million of record. Thats incredibly slow. All fields have indexes. If I do count on each table it take no longer than 20seconds.
Here is what mysql explain shows:

```
mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `loggingquarantine_quarantine`;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                         | key                     | key_len | ref                                                       | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | maddr | index  | PRIMARY                                                               | maddr_partition_tag_idx | 5       | NULL                                                      | 1016497 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mr    | ref    | PRIMARY,msgrcpt_idx_rid,msgrcpt_mail_id_idx,msgrcpt_partition_tag_idx | msgrcpt_idx_rid         | 8       | mroute_logquar.maddr.id                                   |       2 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,msgs_mail_id_idx,msgs_partition_tag_idx                       | PRIMARY                 | 22      | mroute_logquar.mr.partition_tag,mroute_logquar.mr.mail_id |       1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

How can I optimize the query/view so it will not take 13 minutes to make a count.. What's  wrong with a current query?

UPDATE.
If I do a select count directly on select without view its still get same 14 min query.

```
mysql> select count(1) FROM     (((`msgrcpt` `mr` JOIN `msgs` `m` ON     (                  `m`.`partition_tag` = `mr`.`partition_tag`         AND                 `m`.`mail_id` = `mr`.`mail_id`      ) ) JOIN `maddr` maddr ON     (         `mr`.`rid` = `maddr`.`id`     ) ));

+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|  2582227 |
+----------+
1 row in set (14 min 28.96 sec)
```

And here is result for count when I do it in three separate queries :

```
mysql> select count(1) from msgrcpt;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|  2587307 |
+----------+
1 row in set (46.02 sec)

mysql> select count(1) from msgs;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|  2421710 |
+----------+
1 row in set (7.77 sec)

mysql> select count(1) from maddr;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|   994880 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.23 sec)
```

UPDATE 2.

All tables are InnoDB.

```
mysql> SHOW status like 'key_%';                                                                                                                                                                               +------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| Key_blocks_not_flushed | 0     |
| Key_blocks_unused      | 26792 |
| Key_blocks_used        | 0     |
| Key_read_requests      | 0     |
| Key_reads              | 0     |
| Key_write_requests     | 0     |
| Key_writes             | 0     |
+------------------------+-------+
```

The msgs and msgrcpt tables have a composite primary key ( mail_id, partation_tag for msgs and (`partition_tag`,`mail_id`,`rseqnum`) for msgrpt). 
UPDATE
Explain for single tables:

```
mysql> explain select count(1) from msgs;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key               | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | msgs  | index | NULL          | msgs_idx_time_num | 4       | NULL | 2357360 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select count(1) from msgrcpt;
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key            | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | msgrcpt | index | NULL          | msgrcpt_rs_idx | 3       | NULL | 2620758 | Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select count(1) from maddr;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key                     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | maddr | index | NULL          | maddr_partition_tag_idx | 5       | NULL | 967058 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

UPDATE.
Create table for all tables:

```
mysql> show create table msgrcpt;
| Table   | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
| msgrcpt | CREATE TABLE `msgrcpt` (
  `partition_tag` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mail_id` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
  `rseqnum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `is_local` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `content` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ds` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `rs` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `bl` char(1) DEFAULT '',
  `wl` char(1) DEFAULT '',
  `bspam_level` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `smtp_resp` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`partition_tag`,`mail_id`,`rseqnum`),
  KEY `msgrcpt_idx_rid` (`rid`),
  KEY `msgrcpt_mail_id_idx` (`mail_id`),
  KEY `msgrcpt_rs_idx` (`rs`),
  KEY `msgrcpt_ds_idx` (`ds`),
  KEY `msgrcpt_partition_tag_idx` (`partition_tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

| msgs  | CREATE TABLE `msgs` (
  `partition_tag` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mail_id` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
  `secret_id` varbinary(16) DEFAULT '',
  `am_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `time_num` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time_iso` char(16) NOT NULL,
  `sid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `policy` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `client_addr` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `size` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `originating` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `content` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quar_type` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quar_loc` varbinary(255) DEFAULT '',
  `dsn_sent` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spam_level` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `message_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `from_addr` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `subject` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `host` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`partition_tag`,`mail_id`),
  KEY `msgs_idx_sid` (`sid`),
  KEY `msgs_idx_mess_id` (`message_id`),
  KEY `msgs_idx_time_num` (`time_num`),
  KEY `msgs_mail_id_idx` (`mail_id`),
  KEY `msgs_partition_tag_idx` (`partition_tag`),
  KEY `msgs_content_idx` (`content`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ft_from_addr` (`from_addr`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ft_subject` (`subject`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

| maddr | CREATE TABLE `maddr` (
  `partition_tag` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varbinary(255) NOT NULL,
  `domain` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `part_email` (`partition_tag`,`email`),
  KEY `maddr_email_idx` (`email`),
  KEY `maddr_partition_tag_idx` (`partition_tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3373444 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

This query with profile:

```
mysql> SET PROFILING=1; SELECT
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

    -> count(1)
    -> FROM
    ->     (((`msgrcpt` `mr` JOIN `msgs` `m`
    -> ON
    ->     (
    ->                 `m`.`partition_tag` = `mr`.`partition_tag`
    ->         AND
    ->                 `m`.`mail_id` = `mr`.`mail_id`
    ->     )
    -> )
    -> JOIN `maddr` maddr
    -> ON
    ->     (
    ->         `mr`.`rid` = `maddr`.`id`
    ->     )
    -> )); SHOW PROFILE ALL;

+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|  4279394 |
+----------+
1 row in set (23 min 56.61 sec)

+----------------------+------------+-----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------+
| Status               | Duration   | CPU_user  | CPU_system | Context_voluntary | Context_involuntary | Block_ops_in | Block_ops_out | Messages_sent | Messages_received | Page_faults_major | Page_faults_minor | Swaps | Source_function       | Source_file      | Source_line |
+----------------------+------------+-----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------+
| starting             |   0.000161 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | NULL                  | NULL             |        NULL |
| checking permissions |   0.000030 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 1 |     0 | check_access          | sql_parse.cc     |        5043 |
| checking permissions |   0.000019 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | check_access          | sql_parse.cc     |        5043 |
| checking permissions |   0.000020 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | check_access          | sql_parse.cc     |        5043 |
| Opening tables       |   0.000039 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | open_tables           | sql_base.cc      |        5014 |
| System lock          |   0.000026 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_lock_tables     | lock.cc          |         304 |
| init                 |   0.000040 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_select          | sql_select.cc    |        1041 |
| optimizing           |   0.000030 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize              | sql_optimizer.cc |         138 |
| statistics           |   0.000063 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize              | sql_optimizer.cc |         358 |
| preparing            |   0.000032 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | optimize              | sql_optimizer.cc |         470 |
| executing            |   0.000021 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | exec                  | sql_executor.cc  |         137 |
| Sending data         | 999.999999 | 97.014251 |  10.376423 |            681167 |               25822 |      5157072 |       1951032 |             0 |                 0 |                 4 |               277 |     0 | execute               | sql_executor.cc  |         758 |
| end                  |   0.000106 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_select          | sql_select.cc    |        1071 |
| query end            |   0.000017 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc     |        4761 |
| closing tables       |   0.000021 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_execute_command | sql_parse.cc     |        4809 |
| freeing items        |   0.000030 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | mysql_parse           | sql_parse.cc     |        5997 |
| logging slow query   |   0.000059 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             8 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | log_slow_statement    | sql_parse.cc     |        1720 |
| cleaning up          |   0.000019 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |                 0 |                   0 |            0 |             0 |             0 |                 0 |                 0 |                 0 |     0 | dispatch_command      | sql_parse.cc     |        1654 |
+----------------------+------------+-----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------+
18 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Indexes on tables:

```
mysql> show index from msgs;
+-------+------------+------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| msgs  |          0 | PRIMARY                |            1 | partition_tag | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgs  |          0 | PRIMARY                |            2 | mail_id       | A         |     4174440 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgs  |          1 | msgs_idx_sid           |            1 | sid           | A         |     2087220 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgs  |          1 | msgs_idx_mess_id       |            1 | message_id    | A         |     4174440 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgs  |          1 | msgs_idx_time_num      |            1 | time_num      | A         |     1391480 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgs  |          1 | msgs_mail_id_idx       |            1 | mail_id       | A         |     4174440 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgs  |          1 | msgs_partition_tag_idx |            1 | partition_tag | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgs  |          1 | msgs_content_idx       |            1 | content       | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgs  |          1 | ft_from_addr           |            1 | from_addr     | NULL      |     4174440 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
| msgs  |          1 | ft_subject             |            1 | subject       | NULL      |     4174440 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | FULLTEXT   |         |               |
+-------+------------+------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
10 rows in set (0.97 sec)
```

MSGRCPT

```
mysql> show index from msgrcpt;
+---------+------------+---------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name                  | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------+------------+---------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| msgrcpt |          0 | PRIMARY                   |            1 | partition_tag | A         |          29 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgrcpt |          0 | PRIMARY                   |            2 | mail_id       | A         |     5218535 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgrcpt |          0 | PRIMARY                   |            3 | rseqnum       | A         |     5218535 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgrcpt |          1 | msgrcpt_idx_rid           |            1 | rid           | A         |      347902 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgrcpt |          1 | msgrcpt_mail_id_idx       |            1 | mail_id       | A         |     5218535 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgrcpt |          1 | msgrcpt_rs_idx            |            1 | rs            | A         |          29 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgrcpt |          1 | msgrcpt_ds_idx            |            1 | ds            | A         |          29 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| msgrcpt |          1 | msgrcpt_partition_tag_idx |            1 | partition_tag | A         |          29 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------+------------+---------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
8 rows in set (0.70 sec)
```

MADDR:

```
mysql> show index from maddr;
+-------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| maddr |          0 | PRIMARY                 |            1 | id            | A         |     1653970 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| maddr |          0 | part_email              |            1 | partition_tag | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| maddr |          0 | part_email              |            2 | email         | A         |     1653970 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| maddr |          1 | maddr_email_idx         |            1 | email         | A         |     1653970 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| maddr |          1 | maddr_partition_tag_idx |            1 | partition_tag | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.41 sec)
```

Inno db buffer size

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';
+-------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name           | Value      |
+-------------------------+------------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 2147483648 |
+-------------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: How long does it take if you just do a `COUNT` on the litteral `SELECT` statement (instead of the view)?

Comment: It`s still the same 14min. I updated the post with new results

Comment: `select count(1) from msgrcpt;` and `select count(1) from msgs;` shouldn't be that long, even without indexes. run `SHOW status like 'key_%';` and check `Key_blocks_unused`, `Key_reads` and increase MySQL `key_buffer` if needed and try again.

Comment: Few suggestions - not sure how much they'll help, but:   1. As a test while investigating, try losing the entire select list and just changing it directly to SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (((`msgrcpt` `mr` ... etc.  That will just help eliminate the concat & cast functions and see if they are slowing things down.  2. Do you need to join on the m.partition_tag = mr.partition_tag? isn't the mail_id a unique identifier already?  If so, try removing that from the ON clause.   3. As @c2h5oh said, those direct selects are taking wayyyy too long - there must be something wrong there.

Comment: c2h5oh - Key_blocks_unused      | 26792  . All other are zero. But i forget to tell that all tables are innodb, so this can be normal. ANd key buffer doesnt matter for innodb as i guess. And its set to 32mb now.
Manachi - 1)Doesn`t help. 2) No, mail id is not unique.  msgs table has a compiste primary key ( mail_id +partition tag) and msgrcpt has a composite primary key (`partition_tag`,`mail_id`,`rseqnum`). If i remove on partition tag  clause then it complete with 12-30seconds.
 3) All tables are innodb and count on innodb will do a full table scan  so i guess this number can be normal.

Comment: 2) I was wrong about partition_tag. Its still same 14min. It just was finally cached the result. And the original query become 13sec as well. But when i restarted server and tried this query without partition tag it just take 8min.

Comment: Can you run explain for single tables too? It seems indexes aren't used.

Comment: Looks like it used. I update the post with explain for single tables

Comment: While query is in execution, they are more database activity over this tables? Can be a locks issue?

Comment: Complete `CREATE TABLE` statements for all involved tables would be nice to have.

Comment: 1. Please provide the output of : `SET PROFILING=1; [run your query here]; SHOW PROFILE ALL;`. 2. Please run `OPTIMIZE TABLES msgs, msgrcpt, maddr;` (warning, this will lock your tables for a *very* long time, maybe hours). 3. (Just out of curiosity) please provide the output of the step 1 above, again. 4. Please provide the output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE ('innodb_buffer_pool_size');`.

Comment: yes, Yak and biziclop are right. Also, please provide indexes creation syntax. I'ld anyway tend to think this is just a stupid statistics problem. We'll see.

Comment: joins will slow down your query a lot especially over a large data set.  Avoid them if you can where it makes sense.  Perhaps not the answer you want to hear, but you may want to optimize your schema for your query by changing it to remove the need for joins. Furthermore, set the fields that are important to your query to be indices

Comment: biziclop - i updated post with create tables;

Comment: YaK - i update post with output of profile. Will do second and third step today later. 4 -  innodb_buffer_pool_size | 2147483648  .

Comment: Sebas - i updated post with indexes too

Comment: Aldarund, there is no need to do my steps 2 and 3 anymore. The profiling shows the issue is elsewhere. Instead, please provide execution time of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [the rest of your query here];`..

Comment: Yak - mysql> SELECT count(*)     FROM     (((`msgrcpt` `mr` STRAIGHT_JOIN `msgs` `m` ON     (                 `m`.`partition_tag` = `mr`.`partition_tag`         AND                 `m`.`mail_id` = `mr`.`mail_id`     ) ) STRAIGHT_JOIN `maddr` maddr ON     (         `mr`.`rid` = `maddr`.`id`     ) ));
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  4439563 |
+----------+
1 row in set (13 min 41.91 sec)

Comment: Something is very wrong with the server itself. SELECT COUNT(*) against 2M rows table within 46 seconds is way too slow. Could you please tell us more about server environment you use? OS & MySQL versions? Are you using virtual instance? Do you use network attached disks? How loaded is this server?
Could you please provide output for iostat -dx 5 3 and vmstat 5 3 please?

Comment: Further to vfedorkov's comment, can you please let us know what your CPU is?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using some STRAIGHT_JOINs instead of just plain JOINs to vary the order of the tables used in the JOIN?  Sometimes the query optimizer doesn't pick the ideal order for a particular query.  In other words, what kind of performance do you see with this?

```
SELECT
  concat(CAST(`mr`.`mail_id` AS CHAR(255) charset utf8),CAST(`mr`.`partition_tag` AS CHAR(255) charset utf8)) AS `id`,
  `mr`.`mail_id`       AS `mail_id`,
  `mr`.`partition_tag` AS `partition_tag`,
  `mr`.`content`      AS `content`,
  `mr`.`rs`           AS `rs`,
  `m`.`subject`       AS `subject`,
  `m`.`from_addr`     AS `sender`,
  `m`.`time_num`      AS `TIME`,
  `m`.`spam_level`    AS `spam_level`,
  `m`.`size`          AS `size`,
  `m`.`sid`           AS `sid`,
  `maddr`.`email`          AS `email`
FROM
  `msgrcpt` `mr`
    STRAIGHT_JOIN `msgs` `m`
      ON
        `m`.`partition_tag` = `mr`.`partition_tag` AND
        `m`.`mail_id` = `mr`.`mail_id`
    STRAIGHT_JOIN `maddr` maddr
      ON
        `mr`.`rid` = `maddr`.`id`
```

Or since you're using some heavy-duty conversion and casting on the msgrcpt table, what happens if you force it to be JOINed last in the query, like this?

```
SELECT
  concat(CAST(`mr`.`mail_id` AS CHAR(255) charset utf8),CAST(`mr`.`partition_tag` AS CHAR(255) charset utf8)) AS `id`,
  `mr`.`mail_id`       AS `mail_id`,
  `mr`.`partition_tag` AS `partition_tag`,
  `mr`.`content`      AS `content`,
  `mr`.`rs`           AS `rs`,
  `m`.`subject`       AS `subject`,
  `m`.`from_addr`     AS `sender`,
  `m`.`time_num`      AS `TIME`,
  `m`.`spam_level`    AS `spam_level`,
  `m`.`size`          AS `size`,
  `m`.`sid`           AS `sid`,
  `maddr`.`email`          AS `email`
FROM
  `maddr` `maddr`
    STRAIGHT_JOIN `msgrcpt` `mr`
      ON
        `maddr`.`id` = `mr.`rid`
    STRAIGHT_JOIN `msgs` `m`
      ON
        `m`.`partition_tag` = `mr`.`partition_tag` AND
        `m`.`mail_id` = `mr`.`mail_id`
```

You can play around with the order more if you want, there might be a "magic order" that causes your query to zip.  For example, another variation might be:

```
FROM
  `msgs` `m`
    STRAIGHT_JOIN `msgrcpt` `mr`
      ON
        `m`.`partition_tag` = `mr`.`partition_tag` AND
        `m`.`mail_id` = `mr`.`mail_id`
    STRAIGHT_JOIN `maddr`
      ON
        `maddr`.`id` = `mr`.`rid`
```

...and so on.

Also, in your SELECT columns, all of that casting is bound to kill your performance a bit, as it's having to do it for however many rows you're selecting, which could be a lot.  Have you considered just adding a column to the msgrcpt table that is already calculated so that it won't have to do it in the query?  You could add a trigger to the database to update it efficiently and automatically with the calculated value if you don't want to fool with having to account for the extra column in your code.  Normally, using that kind of optimization is a bit of an overkill, but when doing a SELECT query on millions of rows, it might just do the trick.

**EDIT:**  Here is what I would suggest in order to alter your msgrcpt table.  It will make inserting rows slower by a very tiny amount since it's running a trigger to calculate the new column value, but I think it would pay off in speeding up the query you are trying to run by quite a bit.  Standard disclaimer applies--**do not run this on your production database without thoroughly testing it on a test copy first!**

```
-- The UPDATE command will probably take some time to run since it's updating
-- millions of rows. Be patient!
ALTER TABLE `msgrcpt` ADD COLUMN `friendly_id` TEXT NULL AFTER `rs`;
UPDATE `msgrcpt` SET
  `friendly_id` = CONCAT(CAST(`mail_id` AS CHAR(255) CHARSET utf8),
    CAST(`partition_tag` AS CHAR(255) CHARSET utf8));
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trig_calc_id` BEFORE INSERT ON `msgrcpt`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.`friendly_id` =
      CONCAT(CAST(NEW.`mail_id` AS CHAR(255) CHARSET utf8),
        CAST(NEW.`partition_tag` AS CHAR(255) CHARSET utf8));
  END $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trig_update_id` BEFORE UPDATE ON `msgrcpt`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.`friendly_id` =
      CONCAT(CAST(NEW.`mail_id` AS CHAR(255) CHARSET utf8),
        CAST(NEW.`partition_tag` AS CHAR(255) CHARSET utf8));
  END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now instead of selecting that mangled mess of CONCATed CASTed stuff, just select mr.friendly_id (or whatever you choose to name the column).  Your performance should be much better.

Hope this helps, and let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

Join needs BIG mysql load.
In my expreience, 
create temporary table and select data from it,
boost db query speed.

this is my code, code 2 shows 100 times fast speed.
you can change your query code like code 2 style.
for large and complex db query, use temporary table boost db query speed.

1. make temporary tables make query simple and reduce mysql db load.
2. select data from temporary table also needs less db load.

code 1

```
    $sql = " select distinct wr_parent from $write_table where $sql_search ";
    $result = sql_query($sql);
    $total_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

code 2

```
    $sql = " select wr_parent from $write_table where $sql_search ";
    $sql_tmp = " create TEMPORARY table list_tmp_count as $sql ";
    $sql_ord = " select distinct wr_parent from list_tmp_count ";

    @mysql_query($sql_tmp) or die("<p>$sql_tmp<p>" . mysql_errno() . " : " .  mysql_error() . "<p>error file : $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");
    $result = @mysql_query($sql_ord) or die("<p>$sql_ord<p>" . mysql_errno() . " : " .  mysql_error() . "<p>error file : $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");
    $total_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

[mysql temporary table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html)

and if you temporary table's location in tempfs(memory area) speed also doubled.

Answer (score 0):

There're [several methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Join_algorithms) how databases perform table joins. MySQL is using *only [Nested-loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_loop_join) join* as stated in the [section on `EXPLAIN` output](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html). The way Nested-loops work is the key to understand why this query takes so much time.

According to your `EXPLAIN` output, MySQL is scanning the `maddr` table first, therefore you have a loop of `1 016 497` executions. Inside each execution database performs an index scan on a tiny tables twice. Even if the cost of:

- initiating new index scan;
- searching for an entry in the index;
- finalizing the scan

is really small (as data *most likely* will be cached with that many executions), it will take some milliseconds anyway. Then you multiply by `2`, as `msgrcpt` and `msgs` are both scanned in the inner part. And then multiply by the number of executions of the outer loop, which gives you quite some time.

Your view definition has no filters on the returned data, therefore all tables must be scanned and joined. Given how Nested loops are working, it is clear that variant when outer query contains the least amount of cycles is the best performing one. Bearing in mind the size of all the tables, index scans (all 3 tables are scanned on indexes according to `EXPLAIN` output) will be examining:

- `msgrcpt`: log<sub>2</sub>(2587307) + 1 = 22 pages,
- `msgs`: log<sub>2</sub>(2421710) + 1 = 22 pages and
- `maddr`: log<sub>2</sub>(994880) + 1 = 21 page per each scan

in the *worst case* scenarios. This shows that table scan times are comparable and are quite significant, even using index scans. Still, `maddr` is smaller and this is the reason MySQL has chosen to scan it first.

As I see it, the plan chosen by the database is the best one in the given situation. And the fact that MySQL supports only Nested loop joins gives no optimization possibilities, as the outer loop already is the smallest one. [Hash join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_join) might have been used here for a better performance.

---

So, how to make things performing in this situation?

I recommend to use view only for querying data with filters, which will give MySQL more chances to optimize the query and return data fast.

To obtain count of rows, I would go for estimation (if this acceptable), calculating `count(*)` for each individual table and taking the biggest one.

Another way is to redesign schema, making one of the tables a master one, so that the number of the rows in the view should always match the number of rows in the master table. I'm not sure how to do this with the given design, sorry.

If none of the options is acceptable, unfortunately, I see no other ways how to optimize this query.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with King Skippus about two elements... STRAIGHT_JOIN to help overthrow the optimizer execution plan... AND the triggers to preserve pre-aggregates for you.  HOWEVER, if you ever want to apply a WHERE clause to limit, you are shot.

In addition, if all you care about is a COUNT, then vyegorov comment to throw out all the columns would be best.  By having all the other columns forces the data to be pulled from all the actual pages of data.

I would render my query as

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN COUNT(*)
   FROM
      msgrcpt mr
         JOIN msgs m
            ON mr.mail_id = m.mail_id
           AND mr.partition_tag = m.partition_tag
         JOIN maddr
            ON mr.rid = maddr.id
```

and I know you mentioned indexes, but I would have
MsgRcpt table index via (mail_id, partition_tag)
Msgs table index via same (mail_id, partition_tag)
MAddr index on (id)

Now, why one way vs another on the index? I would try to do based on smallest aggregate in the first index field.  Not knowing exactly what your volume basis is (mail id, partition tag ), but take a sample of a customer order system.  You could have 10,000 people ordering something on a single day, but for a given person, one or two orders on a given day.  It would be easier to find the person first and that individual date vs a single day and down to a single person.  This MAY have an impact on the query performance trying to go through a LARGE list first, then small vs small/small.

By doing just a COUNT(*), you get just that a count.  The additional columns from the raw table are not needed and every page being loaded as it only needs the indexed components to qualify the records in the results.

If you DO want all the data, then I would do the same index considerations above, but have the query as...

```
CREATE VIEW
    loggingquarantine_quarantine ( id, mail_id, partition_tag, content, rs, subject, sender, TIME,
    spam_level, size, sid, email ) AS

SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      concat(CAST(mr.mail_id AS CHAR(255) charset utf8), 
             CAST(mr.partition_tag AS CHAR(255) charset utf8)) AS `id`,
      mr.mail_id,
      mr.partition_tag,
      mr.content,
      mr.rs,
      m.subject,
      m.from_addr AS sender,
      m.time_num AS `TIME`,
      m.spam_level,
      m.size,
      m.sid,
      maddr.email
   FROM
      msgrcpt mr
         JOIN msgs m
            ON mr.mail_id = m.mail_id
           AND mr.partition_tag = m.partition_tag
         JOIN maddr
            ON mr.rid = maddr.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Performance may be affected by a view query itselt as well as usage of a view in your code. For more information, read the article - [MySQL VIEW as performance troublemaker](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker).

Workarounds:

- Execute a simple query, do not use the view.
- If you do not want to use this view in another SELECT statements as dataset, then you may try to create a stored procedure instead of view.

Comment: Have you tested that query without view and without COUNT function? The COUNT function may take much time.

Comment: I dont think that selecting all rows is a good idea. When i do this at mysql console mysql gone away :)

Comment: The console tries to read all records. So, it may freeze because of fetch;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using COUNT(*) insted COUNT(1) because MySQL optimizer is quite buggy
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me: I see that your maddr table has a partition_tag id, yet that partition tag is not used in the last JOIN composing the VIEW. Is this as it should be?

Anyhow, it seems to me that your query might benefit from an index on maddr containing both id and email. This should allow extracting email with less I/O directly from the index (it would probably beneficial to evaluate the performances of the various indexes - it seems to me that the index on email field alone, for example, would rarely be used, but it depends on a workflow that you know and I do not, so I might very well be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Ok :), so on one hand you said - we have 2.5 mln entries, on another hand (according to you as well) count returns 4279394 ( which is slightly higher :) ). The possible reason (sorry it's almost 3 am :) ) is - you don't specify full primary key of msgrcpt ( rseqnum is missing ), so in case of optimizer choosing maddr or msgs as a primary table - you could end up with same entries of msgrcpt . Also based on difference in count times for msgrcpt and msgs I'd strongly recommend to defragment msgrcpt. I believe after defragmentation and usage (already recommended) of straight join your problem will disappear (if not - perhaps you could find a way to calculate on the fly - whatever you need to calculate for rseqnum / spam_level , OR, if spam_level is same for the full message - perhaps you could limit selection in the very beginning by providing hard-coded value of rseqnum.

Answer (score -1):

Write a primary key column in `count()` to make it faster.like `count(id)`